# How do I map enums in many-to-one relationship

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I have two enums, the source one is with responses from api and another one is what I want to send to frontend.

```
public enum ApiResponse
{
    A=1,
    B=2,
    C=3,
    D=4
}


public enum DestEnum
{
    A=1,
    BCD=2
}
```

What I am trying to do is:

```
public class ExampleViewModel
{
    public DestEnum foo { get; set; }
}

var response = ApiResponse.C;

result = new ExampleViewModel()
{
    foo = response
};
```

And I want `foo` value to be `DestEnum.BCD`
Is it possible to do with automapper or some custom attributes?

Comment: I want to send strings

Comment: Can't see what you're trying to do from this code. Something like... `API` responses `"Success"`, `"Fail, because B"`, `"Fail, because C"`... but `Frontend` should only receive `"Success"`, `"Fail"`? Is that the type of result you want?

Comment: @XiangWeiHuang Yes, it looks like the thing I want to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you've set your serializer up to send strings already you seem to be just looking for a way to map an X to a Y

How about:

```
public static class EnumExtensions{
  static Dictionary<ApiResponse,DestEnum> _mapDest = 
  new() {
      [ApiResponse.A] = DestEnum.A,
      [ApiResponse.B] = DestEnum.BCD,
      [ApiResponse.C] = DestEnum.BCD,
      [ApiResponse.D] = DestEnum.BCD,
      
  };
    
  public static DestEnum AsDest(this ApiResponse x) => _mapDest[x];
}
```

And then you can convert the ApiRespnse you got to a Dest like:

```
return new BlahViewModel{

  DestEnumProperty = apiResponseEnumValueIGot.AsDest(),
  OtherProp = ...
}
```

Warning, the lookup will blow up if you get any values that aren't mapped; if you think this will ever be possible, consider having an Unknown value in your DestEnum and doing something like:

```
=> _mapDest.TryGetValue(x, out var r) ? r : DestEnum.Unknown
```